# Mistake with lambda function applied on geodataframe's row

Tags: python, geopandas

I trying to transform a 3D geodataframe of points in 2D. So I've develped the function below:

```
def point3D_to_2D(point3D_wkt: shapely.geometry.point.Point) -> shapely.geometry.point.Point:
    print(point3D_wkt)
    point2D_wkt = transform(lambda x, y, z=None: (x, y), point3D_wkt).wkt
    print(point2D_wkt)

    return point2D_wkt
```

My geodataframe's name is `geom`(I've a lot of fantasy!) and the geometry column's name is `geometry`. Using the code below:

```
geom['geometry'] = geom.apply(lambda row : point3D_to_2D(row.geometry))
```

I see this error:

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'geometry'

But using `type(geom)` I see:

```
geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### convert 3D geometry to 2D

- it's a simple case of not using last (3rd) **z** coordinate of point
- no need to work with **WKT** strings
- an issue with your code is you are using `apply()` to **GeoDataFrame**, plus not taking care of `axis=1` to that it will be row by row
- far simpler to work with just **GeoSeries** so no need to consider axis of data frame

```
gdf["geometry"].apply(lambda p: shapely.geometry.Point(p.coords[0][:-1]))
```

#### data source 3D points

- `head(10)` output shows it's 3D geometry (POINT Z)

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import shapely
df = pd.read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_by_elevation")[1]

df["Lat"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Latitude"].replace({"N":"+","S":"-"}, regex=True), errors="coerce")
df["Lon"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Longitude"].replace({"E":"+","W":"-"}, regex=True), errors="coerce")
df["Elevation (m)"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Elevation (m)"], errors="coerce")
df = df.dropna(subset=["Lat","Lon","Elevation (m)"])

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df["Lon"], df["Lat"], df["Elevation (m)"]), crs="epsg:4386")
gdf.head(10)
```

|  | Country/Territory | City Name/s | Continental Region | Latitude | Longitude | Population | Elevation (m) | Lat | Lon | geometry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Nepal | Pokhara | Asia | N28.2096 | E83.9856 | 523000 | 822 | 28.2096 | 83.9856 | POINT Z (83.9856 28.2096 822) |
| 1 | South Africa | Bloemfontein | Africa | S29.116667 | E026.216667 | 747431 | 1395 | -29.1167 | 26.2167 | POINT Z (26.216667 -29.116667 1395) |
| 2 | China | Shanghai | Asia | N31.2304 | E121.4737 | 2.632e+07 | 122 | 31.2304 | 121.474 | POINT Z (121.4737 31.2304 122) |
| 3 | Nepal | Butwal | Asia | N27.6866 | E83.4323 | 120982 | 150 | 27.6866 | 83.4323 | POINT Z (83.4323 27.6866 150) |
| 4 | Italy | Milan | Europe | N45.4625 | E9.186389 | 1.37869e+06 | 122 | 45.4625 | 9.18639 | POINT Z (9.186389 45.4625 122) |
| 5 | Kazakhstan | Pavlodar | Asia | N52.3000 | E76.950000 | 353930 | 123 | 52.3 | 76.95 | POINT Z (76.95 52.3 123) |
| 6 | South Africa | Pretoria | Africa | S25.746111 | E028.188056 | 2.92149e+06 | 1339 | -25.7461 | 28.1881 | POINT Z (28.188056 -25.746111 1339) |
| 7 | Albania | Tirana | Europe | N41.3317 | E019.8172 | 557422 | 110 | 41.3317 | 19.8172 | POINT Z (19.8172 41.3317 110) |
| 8 | Austria | Vienna | Europe | N48.2092 | E016.3728 | 1.89906e+06 | 170 | 48.2092 | 16.3728 | POINT Z (16.3728 48.2092 170) |
| 9 | Belarus | Minsk | Europe | N53.9678 | E027.5766 | 1.98244e+06 | 198 | 53.9678 | 27.5766 | POINT Z (27.5766 53.9678 198) |